# Store Datetime value in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am exporting data `SQL server` table.

One of my columns has `datetime` value in format `1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` .

I have used both `datetime` and `datetime2` datatype in `sql` table schema but I am getting error.

How to store the above value in `sql server` table.

Comment: If  you want milliseconds, then use `datetime2(3)`.

Comment: The error is "Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]".

Comment: The above should work in SQL Server `DATETIME` datatype.

Comment: There are characters T and Z in the value of column as mentioned in question

Comment: That is not a SQL Server error. If a value is supplied that will not convert, SQL Server's error is "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". You may be looking at an issue with Management Studio (or whatever else you're using to access the database). `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')` works without problems.

Comment: `datetime` doesn't have a format. If the column **is** a `datetime` and you're seeing the value `1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`, then it's your presentation layer showing that value; it's nothing to do with the data type.

Comment: Error: "Can't export data, please check failed map task logs"

Comment: What tool are you using to do the export? Again, the errors you're seeing are *not* produced by SQL Server but by whatever is doing the import/export process.

Comment: Your title says "store datetime value ... in table" but your description says "export". It is difficult to help when your question provides conflicting information while also lacking sufficient detail to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this type:

```
datetimeoffset
```

Check the details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

And here is a small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c4b30ffdc8227022683d938a0f64e15).

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATETIMEOFFSET` data type

The `DATETIMEOFFSET` allows you to manipulate any single point in time, which is a datetime value, along with an offset that specifies how much that datetime differs from UTC.

**DATETIMEOFFSET syntax**

```
DATETIMEOFFSET [ (fractional seconds precision) ]
```